# How do I make an inline PDF Viewer

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to open PDF files from assets but inline with other flutter widgets, like in column widget.

I have used `flutter_pdf_viewer` plugin. Although being a good plugin,  it opens PDF files as a new activity instead of embedding them or display them inline  with other widgets.

Can anybody help me figure out how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to embed an interactive pdf viewer, or just a still image?

Comment: interactive pdf viewer

Answer (score 1):

The `flutter_pdf_viewer` plugin has a working MVP for inline pdfs available at the [inline](https://github.com/pycampers/flutter_pdf_viewer/tree/inline) branch.

A full example is available [here](https://github.com/pycampers/flutter_pdf_viewer/blob/inline/example/lib/main.dart).

It still has some stability issues, which are being discussed over [here](https://github.com/pycampers/flutter_pdf_viewer/issues/1).

Answer (score 0):

In the latest master builds of Flutter, there is an [`AndroidView`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7defaca9c95c66ea8eeef3bd5a2c45e1e85a25db/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/platform_view.dart) widget that allows you to display native android views.

Combine with [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) to display an interactive PDF in a widget.

Of course that will only work on Android. Right now there is no comparable solution for iOS.

Comment: can you please share the example. Actually i am new on this platform.

Comment: Sorry, that would be too much work (like hours of work). I would recommend you to re-evaluate if you want to go with Flutter. Inline pdf is not supported, so it would make more sense to write a native android app.

Comment: Why do you want to display the PDF in a widget? If you just want to change the color of the toolbar or add a few action buttons, you can create a "normal" Android Activity and open it from Flutter.